# How do I make an callback to return promise? Can I use Promise.resolve() as my callback function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, callback, promise, amazon-dynamodb

I use dynogels which is an framework to wrap AWS dynamoDB table, I use it to delete my item on the dynamoDB Table, the function they provide is callback functions.

https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels //document

```
// Destroy model using hash and range key
BlogPost.destroy('foo@example.com', 'Hello World!', function (err) { 
console.log('post deleted')
});
```

But I would like to use promise instead of callback, then I am thinking can I put the Promise.resolve in the callback?

```
BlogPost.destroy('foo@example.com', 'Hello World!', Promise.resolve())
.then(()=>{
    console.log('post deleted')
});
```

How do I make an callback to return promise? I can't think anyway can do it so far.

Comment: No, that won't work. You'd need the `new Promise` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple util for that, namely `util.promisify` https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

```js
let util = require('util')

// create a copy and call it yourself ...
util.promisify(BlogPost.destroy).call(BlogPost, 'foo@example.com', 'Hello World!')
.then(()=>{  
  console.log('post deleted')
});



// ... or create a alternative method:
BlogPost.prototype.destroyPromises = util.promisify(BlogPost.destroy)

// later
BlogPost.destroyPromises('foo@example.com', 'Hello World!')
.then(()=>{  
  console.log('post deleted')
});
```